# Comparing Strings in If loop using Coupon.equals

Tags: java, json, string, if-statement, equals

I am reading data from a JSON and am attempting to compare to the validations I want to have.
It works, but is there a better way to do it?

I want it do validate values from "0.025", "0.03", "0.035", "0.04", "0.045", "0.05", etc.. until 1.00

code:

```
 String Coupon = (String) data.get("coupon");
              
if(Coupon.equals("0.025")||Coupon.equals("0.03")||(Coupon.equals("0.035")||Coupon.equals("0.04"))||(Coupon.equals("0.045")||Coupon.equals("0.05"))){
    System.out.println("Valid Data Found");  
}
```

Comment: ok, and what is stopping you from doing so? add those values in a List, and iterate over that, or use the contains method

Comment: Or, as @maloomeister said in his answer, just use HashSet with valid values :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way for you to verify against a fixed set of data is probably to use a `Set` and check if your coupon is contained within the valid data.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString = "0.03";
    Set<String> validCoupons = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList("0.025", "0.03", "0.035", "0.04", "0.045", "0.05"));
    if (validCoupons.contains(inputString)) {
        System.out.println("Valid coupon found!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this：

```
for (double i = 0.025; i <= 1;) {
        String temp=String.valueOf(i);
        if (Coupon.equals(temp)) {
            System.out.println("Valid Data Found");
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(temp));
        BigDecimal num1 = new BigDecimal(temp);
        BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal("0.005");
        BigDecimal addResult = num1.add(num2);
        String addStr=String.valueOf(addResult);
        i=Double.parseDouble(addStr);
    }
```